# Removing a value from a list at a given index but returning the new list and original list

Tags: python

Writing a remove function that removes an item at a certain index and returns that list while returning the original list without the remove item. I am not sure why but when returning the new list and original list, the values are identical.

```
def remove(my_list, index: int):
    new_list = my_list
    new_list.remove(new_list[index])
    return new_list, my_list

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(remove(my_list, 1)
```

My output is `(['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd'])`

What I am trying to get is `(['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`

Comment: `new_list = my_list` does nothing here but make another reference to the same obj. You are still altering `my_list` try `my_list.copy()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Comment: BTW, using `list.remove()` doesn't really make sense here. Use `del new_list[index]` instead.

Comment: Also BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You are altering `my_list` as well as `new_list` as they are technically the same thing. Try using `list.copy`. And as mentioned in the comments using `del` instead of `list.remove` makes more sense and is more readable:

```
def remove(my_list, index: int):
    new_list = my_list.copy()
    del new_list[index]
    return new_list, my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate subsets of the list that exclude the specified index and return that along with the original list:

```
def remove(my_list, index: int):
    return my_list[:index]+my_list[index+1:],my_list
```